# open file in one method, and write in another

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

So I've been trying to fix this bug for days, with different methods and nothing seems to work. Here is what I've simplified my code down to, so I can see what is going wrong.

I am calling the `open()` method first to open the file, read it out to my variable. I am then invoking `save()` and writing back to the same file.

Yet I get an error saying

> The process cannot access the file {$FILE} because it is being used by another process

Is there a solution for this?

```
private void save()
{
    if (currentFile == null)
    {
        saveAs();
    }
    else
    {
        if (File.OpenWrite(currentFile) != null)
        {
            byte[] buffer = null;
            if (currentEncoding == encoding.utf8)
            {
                buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mainTxtBx.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                buffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mainTxtBx.Text);
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes(currentFile, buffer);
        }
    }
}

private void open()
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = homePath;
    openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
    openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        currentFile = openFileDialog.FileName.ToString();
        openFileDialog.Dispose();
        if (File.Exists(currentFile))
        {
            byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(currentFile);
            if (currentEncoding == encoding.utf8)
            {
                mainTxtBx.Text = new string(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(buffer).ToArray());
            }
            else
            {
                mainTxtBx.Text = new string(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(buffer).ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When are you closing the stream that is created by `File.OpenWrite`?

Comment: @Paul from his code, never because there is no reference to the object so it'd impossible to close (except when the GC gets around to calling the finalizer where I believe it gets closed, but that shouldn't be relied upon

Answer (score 4):

Since you use `WriteAllBytes`, you could use `ReadAllBytes` or `ReadAllText` instead of `OpenWrite`.

```
            byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(currentFile);
            if (currentEncoding == encoding.utf8)
            {
                buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mainTxtBx.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                buffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mainTxtBx.Text);
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes(currentFile, buffer);
```

Comment: Wow, I got rid of the if statement and it worked. I'm guessing it's because the File is closed after the block?

Comment: @Apocalypse no, it's because your `if` statement opens the file but never closes it so `WriteAllBytes` tried to open it again when it's already open.  `ReadAllBytes` and `WriteAllBytes` will open, read/write, and close all in that single method call. Calling `Open` yourself means you need to close it yourself

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in the line `if (File.OpenWrite("test.txt") != null)`. File.OpenWrite opens the file for writing and returns a `FileStream`. You're opening the file, then, while the file is still open, attempting to write to the file in the statement `File.WriteAllBytes(currentFile, buffer);`

Try something along these lines:

```
        var writer = File.OpenWrite("test.txt");
        using (writer)
        {
            byte[] buffer = null;
            //...
            writer.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you dont need the if condition `if (File.OpenWrite(currentFile) != null)`

This opens the file and again you are trying to open the same file and write t0 it using WriteAllBytes

Answer (score 1):

There's several problems and potential problems with the code, but the most immediate one is that `WriteAllBytes` does not require calling `OpenWrite`

When you call `OpenWrite` you opened the file for writing with that file object that's returned and you disallow any other attempts to open the file until it's closed again.  Since you never call `Dispose` on it, it will stay locked until your program exits.

And unrelated issue with the code is that you are only disposing of the dialog if the result is `OK` when it should always be disposed regardless.  You should look into the `using` statement to handle disposing of resources.  Dispose needs to be called even if an exception so you either need to wrap code that uses a disposable object in a `try..finally` or use `using` which does that for you.